# Share Meteor accounts between apps with same DB behind reverse proxy

Tags: meteor, reverse-proxy, meteor-accounts

I don't know enough about how Meteor manages sessions and accounts to know if I have more than one app connected to the same MongoDB behind a reverse proxy will work seamlessly when people are logged in.

The idea is that I split functions into separate apps, and yet they can move around the website normally.

So they start using one app at root (/), then move to the helpdesk (/help), which is served by another app connected to the same DB. They logged in on '/', and so will they still be logged in on '/help'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it, and it can work.

I use Nginx and there are a few things to notice (but wasn't part of question so won't put here).

But the key for Meteor is what I found in a comment somewhere: in each app in a subdirectory run `localStorage["Meteor.loginToken"] && Accounts.loginWithToken(localStorage["Meteor.loginToken"])`. Also use the `ROOT_URL` environment variable correctly when starting apps in subdirectories.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Tom: It works fine. I run 2 app on the same db with same creds.

You need to make sure to use `ROOT_URL` to define the URL site (i.e. subdomain.domain it runs on)

You may also want to look into login out people if they log in from a different browser (otherwise someone logged in into an app will also be logged in into the other: may or may not be what you want)

Check out the way to do this with your router of choice; there are several tutorials on the Meteor Guide.